# Merge or join two tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns `Item`, `Qty` and another table with `Product`, `Quantity`.

Table A

| Item | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| a | 10 |
| a | 15 |
| a | 5 |
| b | 10 |

Table b

| Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| a | 10 |
| a | 20 |
| b | 5 |
| b | 5 |

The output that I'm looking for is this:

| item | Qty | Product | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | a | 10 |
| a | 15 | a | 20 |
| a | 5 | *NULL* | *NULL* |
| b | 10 | b | 5 |
| *NULL* | *NULL* | b | 5 |

Comment: Sure. Just toss ROW_NUMBER into a query from table1. And another for table2. Then join those two on your ROW_NUMBER. If you need further help posting table definitions and data in a consumable format.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. From the sample data you posted there is nothing you can use to ensure the order is consistent.

Comment: You could possibly just use a FULL OUTER JOIN here too but without some details about how the rows and each table are related it is impossible to know what the best approach is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have some sort of order to guarantee consistent results. To simulate that, I added IDENTITY columns

### Match Product to Item in Order Based on ROW_NUMBER()

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table2

CREATE TABLE #Table1 (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Item CHAR(1),Qty INT)
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Product CHAR(1),Qty INT)
INSERT INTO #Table1
VALUES ('a',10)
,('a',15)
,('a',5)
,('b',10)

INSERT INTO #Table2
VALUES ('a',10)
,('a',20)
,('b',5)
,('b',5)


;WITH cte_Table1 AS (
    SELECT *,RankNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY ID)
    FROM #Table1
),
cte_Table2 AS (
    SELECT *,RankNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY ID)
    FROM #Table2
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_Table1 AS A
FULL JOIN cte_Table2 AS B
    ON A.Item = B.Product
    AND A.RankNum = B.RankNum
```

Comment: Thanks this query solve my problem thanks a lot !!!